# Запуск N копий функции с различными параметрами в потоке из цикла

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Не могу понять как запустить N копий функции в потоках? Взята простейшая функция выводящая в цикле свой index в консоль. (конструкции вывода из цикла пока не рассматриваем). Пытаюсь понять принцип запуска функции с параметрами в потоке, как я понял, запуск потока осуществляется именно переопределением функции  start() моей функцией GetQueue()?).

Пытаюсь делать как-то так.
queuethread.h

```
#ifndef QUEUETHREAD_H
#define QUEUETHREAD_H

#include <QtSql>
#include <QObject>          // Необходимо для получения указателя на главный поток
#include <QThread>                 // Вывод отладочной информации

class QueueThread : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

  protected:
    void run();
  public:
    explicit QueueThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void GetQueue(int data);
};

#endif // AMXTHREAD_H
```

queuethread.cpp

```
QueueThread::QueueThread(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
 {

 }

 void QueueThread::run()
 {
   this->exec();
 }
void QueueThread::GetQueue(int ima)
{
    while(true)
     {
         qDebug() <<  "\n Privet iz potoka"<<":"<<ima;
     }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "queuethread.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    for(int i=0; i<nReqestChanels; i++) 
    {
        QueueThread *Thread = new QueueThread();
        Thread->GetQueue(i);
        Thread->start();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Насколько мне помнится такой метод работает с одним потоком, если вам нужно создавать много потоков — используйте `QtConcurrent` и указывание максимального количества потоков. Держите сниппет http://pastebin.com/iAz73Na3 (можете загуглить)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду гуглить

Comment: для данной задачи, в моем случае QtConcurrent является решением при известном количестве потоков, а как быть если количество потоков переменное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно решение задачи действительно было найдено через `QtConcurrent`
main.cpp

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
 #include <QString>
 #include <QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrun.h>
 #include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

 #ifndef QT_NO_CONCURRENT

 using namespace QtConcurrent;

 void hello(int number)
 { //while (true)

     for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
     qDebug() <<"\n"<<number<<"\n";// << "from" << QThread::currentThread();
     }
   }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
     int ThreadNumber = 0;
     std::cin >> ThreadNumber;
     QFuture<void> f[ThreadNumber];
     for(int i=0; i<ThreadNumber; i++)
     {
         f[i] = run(hello, i );
         f[i].waitForFinished();
     }
 }

 #else

 int main()
 {
         qDebug() << "Qt Concurrent is not yet supported on this platform";
 }

 #endif
```

process.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
 TARGET +=
 DEPENDPATH += .
 INCLUDEPATH += .

 # входные данные
 SOURCES += main.cpp
 CONFIG += console

 # install
 target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/qtconcurrent/runfunction
 sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$FORMS $$RESOURCES *.pro *.png
 sources.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/qtconcurrent/runfunction
 INSTALLS += target sources
```

при использовании while необходимо закомментировать f[i].waitForFinished();